# Should I say "product of" or "result of" with something abstract?

Tags: word-choice

Should I say *product of* or *result of* with something abstract?

As in,

> These questions are the **product** of my studies.

or

> These questions are the **result** of my studies.

Comment: Is your question in relation to *questions* or abstract things in general?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Without additional context, either word is perfectly acceptable. The definitions of each word should help you decide between the two for the specific context you are dealing with:

> product —
>
> 1. something made or created: something that is made or created by a person, machine, or natural process, especially something that is offered for sale
> 2. company's goods or services: the goods or services produced by a company
> 3. result: something that arises as a consequence of something else
>
> result — consequence: something that follows as a consequence of another action, condition, or event

Note that "product" can literally mean "result". There is not a significant difference between these two words.

Answer (score 0):

result isn't confined to only being a consequence

result is an outcome

where as

product is something that is a result

so, it can be that both are right but, I feel, though it is a shame, that we have to be careful of what we say. Though either one by definition can be used, people have manipulated words to have a specific meaning to them.

In this example, product tends to be misinterpreted as something defined by another influence, which is wrong but a common misconception, none the less. The English language was made for communication to others so, we do have to be aware of how people interpret things and either be ready to explain ourselves or use a word that others are more comfortable with.

the choice is yours...

Comment: Perhaps you should check your spelling and use of capital letters? People have downvoted an answer for less. Just saying.

Answer (score -1):

I reckon to use *outcome* in your sentence.

Comment: We appreciate your answer. You can make this a better answer by providing links, even in answers responding to seemingly opinion-based questions.

Comment: -1 Why would you think neither *product* nor *result* could be used?

Comment: When the question is "product" or "result" and you answer "outcome", it's **not helpful at all**. How about discussing the words, and finally concluding which word to use? ;)

Comment: I'd perhaps use 'upshot' or 'These questions stem from my studies'.

Answer (score -1):

I think "result" is more appropriate, because "product" is something that was produced.

Comment: Hi, Alexiy, and welcome to EL&U. We appreciate your answer. You can make this a better answer by providing links, even in answers responding to seemingly opinion-based questions.